# Python Regex to parse apart android user agent device name

Tags: python, regex, parsing, user-agent

I'm working on parsing apart Android user agents, with Python 2.5, and so far I've been able to figure out a regex which works for "most" android user agents that gathers the major and minor version.

```
(?P<browser>Android) (?P<major_version>\d*).(?P<minor_version>\d*)
```

The above regex works for the example below:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-gb; Nexus One Build/FRF50) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
```

However, I'd like to also get what type of Android device this is. I'm seeing a common pattern in android user agents for where to find the device name using this reference: http://www.botsvsbrowsers.com/category/6/index.html

Basically it always seems to be after the language, such as "en-gb;" and before "Build/"

So how should I modify my regex so that in the example above i would be able to parse out "Nexus One".

Another android user agent example would be:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.1; en-us; HTC Legend Build/cupcake) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17
```

In the above example I'm looking to get "HTC Legend"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?P<browser>Android) (?P<major_version>\d*)\.(?P<minor_version>\d*);[^;]*;(?P<device>[ \w]+) Build\/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(?P<browser>Android)\s(?P<major_version>\d+)\.(?P<minor_version>\d+);[^;]*;\s(?P<device>.+)\sBuild
```